# slide in navigation is jumping

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface

I am making this navigation for my website - but im having some issues. Im not sure why it is behaving like it is, look here: http://www.floatleft.dk/dn-test/

When you push the menus they jump - anyone have an idea on what this can be?

It looks like its where the scrollbars usually are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing padding from the navigations wraps.

Answer (score 0):

no jumping here, wich browser and screen resolution you expirence the issue?
checked with chrome / 1920 x 1200

regards
jan

Comment: thank you - i just found my problem. I cant have padding on my navigation-wrap - im in firefox. But thank you for testing